# Is_valid doesn't seem to be true every time I enter submit

Tags: django

views.py

```
@login_required
def PasswordChange(request):
    print('1')
    #email=User.email
    form=PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
    print('wee')
    return render(request, 'password_change.html', {'form':form})
    print('eee')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('doo')
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('2')
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            print('3')
            return render(request, 'success.html')

        else:
            form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
```

'''

urls.py

```
path('passwordchange/',  views.PasswordChange, name='passwordchange'),
```

templates

```
{%block content%}
<form class="form-vertical" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}<br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
{%endblock content%}
```

[31/Mar/2020 18:07:30] "GET /passwordchange/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3919

Not Found: /passwordchange/.jpg

[31/Mar/2020 18:07:30] "GET /passwordchange/.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 8192

1

wee

[31/Mar/2020 18:08:00] "POST /passwordchange/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3919

Not Found: /passwordchange/.jpg

[31/Mar/2020 18:08:00] "GET /passwordchange/.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 8192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a return after `print('wee')`:

`return render(request, 'password_change.html', {'form':form})`.

This means your code will not execute anything after the return.